# Turning a 1-D Array into a 2-D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to take an array that contains 400 integers, and split it into a 20x20 2-D array. I thought I had the right algorithm, but the sum of the 1-D array does not match the sum of the 2-D array, so I’m obviously doing something wrong. Here is my code:

```
private static void processArray(int[] inArray)
{
    int[][] array = new int[20][20];

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 400; z++)
            {
                array[x][y] = inArray[z];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the last element in the input array to every element in the output array. The inner loop over the input array must be changed into a single assignment that picks the correct input element.

```
private static void processArray(int[] inArray)
{
    int[][] array = new int[20][20];

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = inArray[x * 20 + y];  // or devise your own calculation
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For each pair of `x` and `y`, your code assigns *every* value from `inArray` to `array[x][y]`. This is clearly incorrect.

Here is one way to fix the code:

```
private static void processArray(int[] inArray)
{
    int[][] array = new int[20][20];

    for (int x = 0, z = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = inArray[z++];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The current approach will assign each element in the array with the last element in the original.

You should not iterate `z` but use it as a counter, in the same loops.

```
int z = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
                array[x][y] = inArray[z++];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basically assigning array[x][y] equal to inArray[0], then inArray[1], then inArray[2], all the way to [400].

I would do something like

```
private static void processArray(int[] inArray)
{
    int[][] array = new int[20][20];

    for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
        {
            array[x][y] = inArray[x * 20 + y];
        }
    }
}
```